# Problema com comparação de ponto flutuante

Tags: c

Olá!
Estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade e uma das partes que tenho que fazer é pegar o valor de h e ver se ele é positivo e entre 0.8 e 1.2. É muito simples, porém quando eu digito 0.8, ele aceita!! Alguém poderia me ajudar? por favor. Outra coisa, quando dizem 'entre', os números que foram usados para medir de qual até qual número pegar, também entram (0.8, 1.2)?

```
float h;
do{
    printf("Por favor, digite o tamanho do nivel em cm (entre 0.8 e 1.2): \n");
    scanf("%f",&h);
    if(h<0){
        printf("Favor, insira um valor positivo!\n");
    }
}while(!(h>0&&(h>0.8&&h<1.2)));
```

Comment: Não ficaria bem mais simples fazer simplesmente `while (h<0.8 || h>1.2)))` já que, pelo que entendi você quer um numero no intervalo `[0.8, 1.2]`?

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou :(. Por algum motivo quando implemento o que você comentou, o código não aceita o 1.2 e aceita o 0.8 (o estranho aqui seria ele aceitar o 0.8). Já tentei colocar até >= e <= para o 0.8 e 1.2, porém por algum motivo o 1.2 não vai :(

Comment: Este é o problema da imprecisão inerente da representação de números de ponto flutuante. Veja este teste: https://ideone.com/G7e4Xo que você verificará que 1.2 não é precisamente representado.

Comment: @anonimo, tomei a liberdade de fazer um *fork* do seu código. Usando *literals* de ponto flutuante o erro de precisão é o mesmo dos dois lados e a comparação funciona como esperado (https://ideone.com/zMadkX). O problema no caso é a comparação do tipo `float` de um lado, com *literals* do tipo `double` do outro.

Comment: @Anthony Accioly: perfeito. Este é um aspecto totalmente negligenciado pelos iniciantes (principalmente se envolver operações aritméticas). Se definir `h` como `double` também obterá o resultado esperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta não ficou tão clara, porém se o que você precisa é pegar os números entre **0.8** e **1.2** incluindo o **0.8** e o **1.2** é só você usar o operador **OR** ( `||` ), segue o código:

```
float h;

do{
    printf("Por favor, digite o tamanho do nivel em cm (entre 0.8 e 1.2): \n");
    scanf("%f",&h);
    if(h<0){
        printf("Favor, insira um valor positivo!\n");
    }
}while(h < 0.8f || h > 1.2f);
```

Como você já tratou o caso de `h < 0` no corpo do laço, não vejo necessidade de tratar novamente na condição do laço.

Comment: Fiz exatamente como você fez, porém por algum motivo, quando fui testar com os números 0.8 e 1.2, o 0.8 foi aceito, sendo que não há nenhum sinal de igualdade nos < e >. O mais estranho é que o 1.2 não foi aceito (o que estaria certo, pois não há >= nem <= na condição). Ou seja, por algum motivo o 0.8 entra e o 1.2 não.

Comment: Victor, a condição no `while` é a de falha, ou seja, todos os números que você quer rejeitar. Se 0.8 deve ser rejeitado então você de fato precisa de um `<=`. Outra coisa, você está comparando um float (`h`) com dois *literals* do tipo `double` (`0.8` e `1.2`). Eu recomendaria ou usar `float` para tudo (`while(h <= 0.8f || h >= 1.2f)`) ou usar `double` para tudo (ou seja, usar `double h;` e `"%lf"` no `scanf`).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly você está certo, obrigado pelo aviso, a resposta foi corrigida. Eu apenas corrigi o código do VictorHugo22 e não vi esse detalhe do float.

Comment: @VictorHugo22 o problema com o '1.2' é a diferença de precisão entre 'float' e 'double', de acordo com a resposta do  Anthony Accioly e a correção feita você deve conseguir.

Comment: Consegui!!! Muito obrigado Lucas Oliveira e Anthony Accioly. O problema estava com a comparação do tipo float com double. Utilizei 0.8f e 1.2f e funcionou! Nunca tinha visto isso antes! Bom que agora aprendi algo novo. Mais uma vez... obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Bom o código que o colega deu como resposta está correto, digamos que vc quer um intervalo entre 1 - 3, se você colocar aa condição (input < 1 || input > 3) ele vai receber valores menores que 1, ou seja o 1 está incluso na condição, pois apenas numeros menores que ele não entram, se vc quiser excluir o 1 da condição use (input < 2 || input > 3), assim os números 2 e 3 serão inclusos na condição.

No seu caso coloque a condição (h < 0.8f || h > 1.2f) mesmo, como o amigo disse, fiz aqui sem utilizar o "do", confere ai:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void)
   {
     float h = 0;

     while (h < 0.8f || h > 1.2f){
        printf("Por favor, digite o tamanho do nivel em cm (entre 0.8 e 1.2): \n");
        scanf("%f", &h);
        if (h < 0){
           printf("Favor, insira um valor positivo!\n");
        }
   }

   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Obrigado por ter me respondido Gustavo Macedo Rodrigues! o meu problema foi ter colocado && ao invés de ||. Também coloquei o 'f' depois do 0.8 e 1.2, assim como você fez! Agora já posso entregar o meu trabalho! Obrigado mais uma vez.